# Jetbrains IntelliJ / Rider HttpClient generate POST request body

Tags: openapi, jetbrains-ide, rider

Is there a way to generate Post Json object from EndPoint window ?

There is OpenApi 3.0 specs for this aspnetcore web app

Currently having to import OpenApi file into Postman, which generates Post Json object automatically